# I have a dataset in R with 3 columns of numbers that I need to convert to a vector of dates

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

in this data.frame the three variables are month, dayOftheMonth ,dayOfTheWeek, all the data is in the same year. I need to convert these columns to a vector for plotting using ggplot2

variable info:

date_cols = `data.frame(month=1:12, dayOftheMonth=1:31, dayOfTheWeek=1:7)` #(monday=1)

Comment: check out `mdy` function from `lubridate` package

Answer (score 0):

In this case you only really need the month and the day of the month, so with

```
dd<-data.frame(month=rep(1:3, each=5), 
    dayOftheMonth=rep(seq(1,length.out=5, by=5), 3))
```

I can covert that data to dates with

```
as.Date(sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", 2014, dd$month, dd$dayOftheMonth))
```

All we do is convert to a canonical date-time format and add in the year, then we use `as.Date` to do the transformation.